# Enable lightdm autologin using sed

Tags: sed, configuration, lightdm

I need to edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` using `sed` inside specific section, uncomment and set value.

This section is `[Seat:*]` and line is `#autologin-user=`

I expect this change:
Before:

```
[LightDM]
.
.
.
[Seat:*]
.
.
.
#autologin-user=
.
.
.
```

After:

```
[LightDM]
.
.
.
[Seat:*]
.
.
.
autologin-user=pi
.
.
.
```

I've tried this command:

```
sed -i.bak '/^\[Seat:*]/{s/#autologin-user/autologin-user=pi/}' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

But without success.

PS: There are more occurrences of `#autologin-user`, so selecting section `[Seat:*]` is really important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this, given an altered input file sample:

```
[LightDM]
[Seat:*]
#autologin-user=
[Foo:*]
#autologin-user=
[Bar:*]
#autologin-user=
```

The command:

```
$ sed '/^\[Seat:\*\]$/,/\[/s/^#autologin-user=$/autologin-user=pi/' foo.txt 
[LightDM]
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=pi
[Foo:*]
#autologin-user=
[Bar:*]
#autologin-user=
```